# To understand a C code about endianness

Tags: c, endianness

I am studying [big and little-endianness](http://www.netrino.com/node/149).

**1. What is the purpose of `| \` in the following code?**

```
...

#elif defined(LITTLE_ENDIAN) && !defined(BIG_ENDIAN)

  #define htons(A) ((((uint16_t)(A) & 0xff00) >> 8) | \
                    (((uint16_t)(A) & 0x00ff) << 8))
...
```

**2. What is the purpose of `(A)` in the code?**

Comment: You don't need either mask & 0xff00 or & 0x00ff - in the first case the bottom 8 bits are masked because they shift off the bottom. In the second case the bits overflow and are lost. (uint16_t)(((uint16_t)(A) >> 8) | ((uint16_t)(A) << 8))) would have the same result

Comment: @Tom Leys disagree about the 2nd case.  `(( (uint16_t)(A) ) << 8))`. `A` is cast to `uint16_t` retaining its 16 LSbits.  Then it goes thought the usual integer promotions which may be to a 32-bit `int` for example.  Then that value is shifted 8.  Not likely what OP desired.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The '|' is the bitwise OR operator.  It basically combines the values.  The 'A' is the parameter from the #define htons.  It is enclosed in parentheses so that expressions will not confuse the programmer or compiler.  The '\' continues the macro onto the next line.  (A macro usually ends at the end of the line.)

This macro takes the 16-bit value in A and masks out the top 8 bits. It then takes that value and shifts it right 8 bits.  That means the top 8 bits are now on the bottom of the 16-bit value.  It next masks out the top 8 bits of the original value in A and shifts those left 8 bits.  That means the bottom 8 bits are now on the top.  Finally, it recombines the two values back into one value.

The end result is that the top and bottom bytes have had their places swapped.

Answer (score 4):

This code is nothing more than standard C-preprocessor Macros.

The `|` is the bitwise OR operator. The `\` escapes the newline so that the `#define` can continue to the next line. The `(A)` is a parameter for the macro.

Answer (score 3):

| performs a bitwise "OR" on two integers
\ is an escape character that allows a #define to cotninue onto the next line

Comment: I got to the question 30 seconds too late it seems. :P

Answer (score 2):

It's a macro, it'll get expanded when you uses it.

If you e.g. use("call") the macro as

```
uint16_t i = htons(0x1234);
```

It will expand to:

```
uint16_t i =  ((((uint16_t)(0x1234) & 0xff00) >> 8) |(((uint16_t)(0x1234) & 0x00ff) << 8));
```

It's not that unlike a variable in a function, e.g.

```
uint16_t htons(uint16_t A) 
{
   return (A & 0xff00) >> 8) | (A & 0x00ff) << 8);
}
```

Comment: For one of the most important revelations to a C/C++ programmer, consider what `uint16_t i = 0x1233; uint16_t j = htons(i++);` results in.